# Reconfigure RAID on Dell PowerEdge T710

Tags: raid

I have a Dell PowerEdge T710 under my feet at this very moment, with RedHat Enterprise Server 5.3.

I have 6 1TB disks and two 500GB. parted reports two devices, one 500 GB and the other 4 TB. So I assume the RAID has been setup as mirror for two disks, and I assume as RAID 5 the remaining ones. I say "I assume" because it does not make sense. Having 6 disks in RAID 5, I should obtain a total space of 5 TB, not 4TB. It's not even RAID 10: I would end up with a 3 TB unit.

How can I check and eventually modify the RAID array definition? In the Fujitsu Siemens I played with some time ago, at boot I had the chance to enter the controller BIOS, but here I don't see a clear way to perform this operation.

Comment: Raid6 would give you 4TB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this :

`wget -q -O - http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/latest/bootstrap.cgi | bash`

and then :

`yum install srvadmin-all`

And then in /opt you will have all the dell tools and you will be able to use omreport to look at the raid setup - docs are here : http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/svradmin/1.9/en/cli/cli_cc5s.htm

Comment: thanks. So there's no way to access it directly from BIOS, as far as I understand.

Comment: Yeah there sure there is - just assumed you wanted to do it from within the OS ;-)

To get to the BIOS you need to press CTRL+R during the boot - it should say something like : "PowerEdge Expandable RAID Controller BIOS" - at that point do CTRL+R

Comment: That is correct but the T710 ships with a PERC 6i - and the key combo for that is CTRL+R - and as the server has RAID in hardware I find it unbelievable that anyone would have used softraid in its place.

Comment: Ok, now I have trouble with the RedHat Network registration, so I cannot download the tools right now. I however tried the Ctrl+R command, and I'm in the BIOS now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It may be configured as a 'hot spare'.